# Can anyone explain how the symbol "=>" is used in Scala

Tags: scala

I've read a lot of code snippets in scala that make use of the symbol `=>`, but I've never really been able to comprehend it. I've tried to search in the internet, but couldn't find anything comprehensive. Any pointers/explanation about how the symbol is/can be used will be really helpful.

(More specifially, I also want to know how the operator comes into picture in function literals)

Comment: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/book-index.html#indexanchor search for "rocket"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help in understanding a scala code snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530132/need-help-in-understanding-a-scala-code-snippet) (this is the earlier but the other includes a code snippet so it is more answerable IMHO)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

More than passing values/names, `=>` is used to define a function literal, which is an alternate syntax used to define a function.

Example time. Let's say you have a function that takes in another function. The collections are full of them, but we'll pick `filter`. `filter`, when used on a collection (like a List), will take out any element that causes the function you provide to return false.

```
val people = List("Bill Nye", "Mister Rogers", "Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi", "Jesus", "Superman", "The newspaper guy")
// Let's only grab people who have short names (less than 10 characters)
val shortNamedPeople = people.filter(<a function>)
```

We *could* pass in an actual function from somewhere else (`def isShortName(name: String): Boolean`, perhaps), but it would be nicer to just place it right there. Alas, we can, with function literals.

```
val shortNamedPeople = people.filter( name => name.length < 10 )
```

What we did here is create a function that takes in a String (since `people` is of type `List[String]`), and returns a Boolean. Pretty cool, right?

This syntax is used in many contexts. Let's say *you* want to write a function that takes in another function. This other function should take in a String, and return an Int.

```
def myFunction(f: String => Int): Int = {
  val myString = "Hello!"
  f(myString)
}
// And let's use it. First way:
def anotherFunction(a: String): Int = {
  a.length
}
myFunction(anotherFunction)
// Second way:
myFunction((a: String) => a.length)
```

That's what function literals are. Going back to `by-name` and `by-value`, there's a trick where you can force a parameter to not be evaluated until you want to. The classic example:

```
def logger(message: String) = {
  if(loggingActivated) println(message)
}
```

This looks alright, but `message` is actually evaluated when `logger` is called. What if `message` takes a while to evaluate? For example, `logger(veryLongProcess())`, where `veryLongProcess()` returns a String. Whoops? Not really. We can use our knowledge about function literals to force `veryLongProcess()` not to be called until it is actually needed.

```
def logger(message: => String) = {
  if(loggingActivated) println(message)
}
logger(veryLongProcess()) // Fixed!
```

`logger` is now taking in a *function* that takes no parameters (hence the naked `=>` on the left side). You can still use it as before, but now, `message` is only evaluated when it's used (in the `println`).