# Need help in understanding a scala code snippet

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone explain how the symbol “=>” is used in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529582/can-anyone-explain-how-the-symbol-is-used-in-scala)

```
val list = List("abc", "cde", "fg")
list.count (s => s.length == 3)
```

The above code snippet returns the number of string elements in `list` whose length is equal to `3`. But I'm not able to understand the snippet as I'm having trouble to grasp the usage of the `=>` operator in this context. Any explanation will be realy helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Scala can be pretty hard to understand. I'll do my best to explain it, though I might not get it right either.

The `List.count` method takes as a parameter a `block` of code that returns a boolean.

Blocks are just little snippets of code and can be created in many ways eg by enclosing code in `{ }`

In the scala docs this is described as

```
def count (p : (A) => Boolean) : Int
```

so `count` takes a parameter `p` which is a block that takes an argument of type `A` and returns a `Boolean`

So in this example:

```
s => s.length == 3
```

is a `block` of code. Blocks usually follow the format

```
[arguments] => [Code to execute]
```

So in this instance `s` is the input to the block and `s.length == 3` is the code that should return a boolean. You can name the arguments whatever you like, so long as they are in the correct order.

When using a method that iterates over a collection, eg `count`, `map`, `each`, etc, the argument passed will be the current item in the collection it is iterating over.

If you want to learn more about it you should check out the Coursera course that is being run my Martin Odersky (the creator of scala) and will be covering details like this in great detail: https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun

Comment: Precisely, the kind of explanation I was looking for :) Thanks. Incidentally, I am taking the coursera course, and the code snippet was in one of the learning resources!

Comment: Ah I see. I'm doing the course as well. Good luck on the assignment due on friday. BTW I created a google calendar that I plan to keep up to date on assignments: n8ucksji7l2t7a1ne45fn5i35k@group.calendar.google.com add that email to Other Calendars in Google Calendar if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

This just defines a method, you can also see it this way:

```
def isValid(s:String) = s.length ==3
list.count(isValid)
```

So, when you use the count function, you give it a condition which is a function as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

(I didn't see that you posted another (re-worded) question. Here's what I answered to your first one)

More than passing values/names, `=>` is used to define a function literal, which is an alternate syntax used to define a function.

Example time. Let's say you have a function that takes in another function. The collections are full of them, but we'll pick `filter`. `filter`, when used on a collection (like a List), will take out any element that causes the function you provide to return false.

```
val people = List("Bill Nye", "Mister Rogers", "Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi", "Jesus", "Superman", "The newspaper guy")
// Let's only grab people who have short names (less than 10 characters)
val shortNamedPeople = people.filter(<a function>)
```

We *could* pass in an actual function from somewhere else (`def isShortName(name: String): Boolean`, perhaps), but it would be nicer to just place it right there. Alas, we can, with function literals.

```
val shortNamedPeople = people.filter( name => name.length < 10 )
```

What we did here is create a function that takes in a String (since `people` is of type `List[String]`), and returns a Boolean. Pretty cool, right?

This syntax is used in many contexts. Let's say *you* want to write a function that takes in another function. This other function should take in a String, and return another String.

```
def myFunction(f: String => Int): Int = {
  val myString = "Hello!"
  f(myString)
}
// And let's use it. First way:
def anotherFunction(a: String): Int = {
  a.length
}
myFunction(anotherFunction)
// Second way:
myFunction((a: String) => a.length)
```

That's what function literals are. Going back to `by-name` and `by-value`, there's a trick where you can force a parameter to not be evaluated until you want to. The classic example:

```
def logger(message: String) = {
  if(loggingActivated) println(message)
}
```

This looks alright, but `message` is actually evaluated when `logger` is called. What if `message` takes a while to evaluate? For example, `logger(veryLongProcess())`, where `veryLongProcess()` returns a String. Whoops? Not really. We can use our knowledge about function literals to force `veryLongProcess()` not to be called until it is actually needed.

```
def logger(message: => String) = {
  if(loggingActivated) println(message)
}
logger(veryLongProcess()) // Fixed!
```

`logger` is now taking in a *function* that takes no parameters (hence the naked `=>` on the left side). You can still use it as before, but now, `message` is only evaluated when it's used (in the `println`).