# Function literal - Need help in understanding a code snippet

Tags: scala

I'm basically new to functional programming and scala, and the following question might possibly look stupid.

```
val f = (a:Int) => a+1
```

In the above snippet, should I consider `f` to be a function or a variable? Coming from a C/C++ background, the first thought that occurs is that `f` is a variable that stores the return value of the anonymous function, but I think that's not the correct way to interpret it Any explanation would be really helpful.

(Some of the terminologies I used above might be wrong with respect to scala/functional programming, kindly bear with it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, `f` is a variable that stores a function.  It's really no different from saying any of the following:

```
val a = 4               // `a` is a variable storing an Int
val b = "hi"            // `b` is a variable storing a String
val f = (a:Int) => a+1  // `f` is a variable storing a function
```

You can also confirm this with the REPL:

```
scala> val f = (a:Int) => a+1
f: Int => Int = <function1>
```

So this is telling you that `f` has the type `Int => Int`. Or in other words, `f` is a function that takes one argument, an `Int`, and returns an `Int`.

Since `f` is a variable, you can call methods on it or pass it as an argument to functions that expect its type:

```
a + 3  // here I'm calling the `+` method on `a`, which is an Int
f(3)   // here I'm calling the `apply` method on `f`, which is a function `Int => Int`
f(a)   // the function `f` expects an `Int`, which `a` is
(1 to 3).map(f)  // the `map` method expects a function from Int to Int, like `f`
```

Comment: Don't say "variable", that's very confusing. It is a value, you cannot overwrite it with any new value. The term variable should be reserved for `var`s, and value should be used for `val`s. It is only a variable in the sense of a __place-holder__, and that's probably how you meant it.

Comment: @0__: The Scala spec uses the word "variable" even when the value can't be changed, as does the Haskell spec, just about every math textbook ever, etc. You may think the standard usage is potentially confusing, but trying to change it is not a battle you're going to win.

Comment: @Travis - I wasn't aware of that. Sometimes people use "write-once variable" or "immutable variable", etc.; the latter for me is especially contradictory. But I can see this coming from Java, you can have `final int i` and then "write it" later down in the code. In that sense it's more like a mathematical or dataflow variable, meaning 'unknown value, yet to be determined'; my thought was that a Scala `val` does not have this separation of definition-without-value-but-just-type and then eventual assignment. But of course on the top-level you can do `trait X { val unknown: Int }`. Hmmm....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like dhg said, `f` is a variable (that can't be changed) that stores a function.

However, there's a subtlety here:

> ... the first thought that occurs is that f is a variable that stores the
>   return value of the anonymous function

`f` actually stores *the function*, not the result. So you can give it different inputs, and get different outputs. So, you can use it like `f(7)` and then `f(5)`. Functions in Scala are objects, so can be assigned to variables, passed as parameters, etc.

[I recently posted about function literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12530324/1214194), which may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

`f` is a value *denoting* a function literal.

In the statement, the right-hand-side is a function literal. The left-hand-side binds it to a name which is then called **value** (the `val` keyword is similar to `let` in LISP). Now the function is associated with the symbol `f`, so you can refer to that function by using this symbol `f`.

I disagree with the other answers which suggest that `f` should be called a variable. `f` is a value, because it is fixed to the right-hand-side term which is determined **only once** and **cannot change**. On the contrary a variable, introduced with `var`, allows you to re-assign values to a symbol:

```
var f = (i: Int) => i + 1
```

Where `var` begins a variable definition, `f` is the name or symbol of the variable, there could be an optional `: ...` defining type of the variable (if you leave that out, the type is automatically inferred from the assignment), and `= ...` defines the value *initially* assigned to the variable.

So when one says *value*, don't confuse this with a numeric constant, it is simply an **entity that doesn't change**. A function can be a value too, because `f` then always denotes this same identical function, even if you can feed that function with different arguments which yield different results.

Now with the `var` you can re-assign its right-hand-side:

```
f(2) // --> 3
f = (i: Int) => i * 2 // assign a new function to the variable f.
f(2) // --> 4
```

Functional programming is all about avoiding variables (re-assignments).

---

It is also possible to define a function without assigning it at all (to a value or a variable). The following defines such a function and immediately calls it with argument `4`:

```
{ i: Int => i + 1 } apply 4 // --> 5
```

although that is seldom useful as a statement per se, but you will see 'plain' functions often when calling a method that expects a function argument. For instance

```
val s = List(1, 2, 3)
s.map { (i: Int) => i + 1 } // --> List(2, 3, 4)
s.map { _ + 1 }             // equivalent
s.map( _ + 1 )              // equivalent
```

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt; as mentioned in the comments above, often both a `val` and a `var` are called variables, even in the literature, using perhaps "write-once" or "immutable variable" to distinguish the former from the latter.